# Receiving 10 times same Push?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6, kinvey

I am sending a push from my custom endpoint logic, but I am receiving it 10 times on my phone?

- What could be the possible cause of receiving multiple times one push message ?

Comment: You should *always* add the **delphi** tag to your Delphi related questions. If you ever wonder about low attention to your question, that is the reason. (the same with all tags containing a special version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it is a strange bug related to the 1st registered device. 
The devices after does not having it.